# Cannot get Web API to work in VS 2010 or 2012

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a machine with the RC of VS 2012 and VS2010 running on it.  I am trying to follow the code on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api to try out Web API.  I tried following on the web some different links on how to fix problems, but still cannot get Web API to work using IIS Express/Cassini for the host on my Windows 7 x64 box.  Currently I am getting "Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.set_IgnoreSerializableAttribute(Boolean)'." error when trying to look at what should be the list of products.

I followed the web page exactly as it is written and didn't add anything manually.  I did set up the nightly repository for the web stack http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/, but don't know if that is causing the problem.  Here's a dump of the NuGet's Get-Package on the program if it helps.

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                                                      
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
EntityFramework                5.0.0-rc             Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.                                                                                                                       
jQuery                         1.6.2                jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library....                                                                                                                                                                 
jQuery.UI.Combined             1.8.11               jQuery UI is an open source library of interface components — interactions, full-featured widgets, and animation effects — based on the stellar jQuery javascript library . Each component is built accordin...
jQuery.Validation              1.8.1                This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of option for customization. That makes a good choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when y...
knockoutjs                     2.0.0                A JavaScript MVVM library to help you create rich, dynamic user interfaces with clean maintainable code                                                                                                        
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc           4.0.20505.0          This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you ...
Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.... 1.0                  ASP.NET Universal Providers add provider support in ASP.NET 4 for all editions of SQL Server 2005 and later and to SQL Azure. If you use these providers to develop your application, the application will b...
Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.... 1.0                  ASP.NET Universal Providers add provider support in ASP.NET 4 for all editions of SQL Server 2005 and later and to SQL Azure. If you use these providers to develop your application, the application will b...
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor         2.0.20505.0          This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages. ASP.NET Web Pages and the new Razor syntax provide a fast, terse, clean and lightweight way to combine server code with HTML to create d...
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.0.0-beta2          ASP.NET Optimization introduces a way to bundle and optimize css/js files.                                                                                                                                     
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi        4.0.20505.0          This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on IIS. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers a...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20505.0          This package adds support for formatting and content negotiation to System.Net.Http. It includes support for JSON, XML, and form URL encoded data.                                                             
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core   4.0.20505.0          This package contains the core runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web API. This package is used by hosts of the ASP.NET Web API runtime. To host a Web API in IIS use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost packag...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... 4.0.20505.0          This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on IIS. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers a...
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages      2.0.20505.0          This package contains core runtime assemblies shared between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages.                                                                                                                
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 2.0.20505.0          jQuery plugin that lets you unobtrusively set up jQuery Ajax.                                                                                                                                                  
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 2.0.20505.0          jQuery plugin that unobtrusively sets up jQuery.Validation.                                                                                                                                                    
Microsoft.Net.Http             2.0.20505.0          This package provides a programming interface for modern HTTP applications. This package includes HttpClient for sending requests over HTTP, as well as HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage for proce...
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure   1.0.0.0              This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically register HTTP modules at run time.                                                                                   
Modernizr                      2.0.6                Modernizr adds classes to the <html> element which allow you to target specific browser functionality in your stylesheet. You don't actually need to write any Javascript to use it....                        
Newtonsoft.Json                4.5.1                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                                                                                                                                 
WebGrease                      1.0.0                Web Grease is a suite of tools for optimizing javascript, css files and images.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on the "Include Prerelease" for NuGet and updated all the packages to the latest nightly release.  It fixed the problem in VS 2012.  Don't know about VS2010 though.

Comment: How to turn on "Include Prerelease" for NuGet  with VS2012 ?

Comment: When managing the NuGet Packages, at the top of the screen you have "Stable Only" next to the Sort By drop down.  Change Stable Only to "Include Prerelease"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. The problem in that case is related to packages, and namely it was http://json.codeplex.com/ (Newtonsoft.Json.dll) package which is used by System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll.

Locally I installed MVC 4 several months ago (before summer), but on my hosting server - much more later. So, when I was working locally, everything was working great... and that was even working great on the server, because I was just updating binaries from svn. However, recently I needed to debug some stuff on the server and the "Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization." problem appeared.
So, after some short explorations I've found the mentioned above cause of the problem.

But everything was working for me even with 4 (not 4.5) .NET Framework version. So, would I have to install 4.5 on my server just for some small project which use no features from it?!! So, I've just replaced C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll from my local PC for convenient compilation. In that case I did not update neither .NET to 4.5 nor json. But if you have 4.5 installed, you just need to update Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

*Anyway, that's really very weird error message in the century of "modern technologies" and such a big progress in .NET development (it rather reminds some linker messages from c/c++ world). Probably, this is all about sense of free (and open-source) software, when developers does not have much time (or even will) for such features supporting.*

Answer (score 0):

I use VS 2010 and I updated the lastest version of Json.NET and the problem is resolved